# German work visa application passport submission

Tags: working-visas, germany

I need to apply for a German work visa. I found that the application process can take up to two months and that you need to submit your passport along with the application. Is this correct?

I live and work in Hong Kong on a valid work visa, and I am an Indian passport holder. Submitting my passport is a bit risky as I am in a foreign country and I may require it quite often. Is there another solution to this situation?

Comment: Can you get a second passport from your consulate? Regular or emergency? That should take care of things, should you need to travel urgently. That's what I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted the German embassy and share my concerns.
They gave me my passport back with a stamp of visa application submitted.So, I can keep my passport with me while they are processing my visa application. They will call me once visa confirmed at that time I need to submit visa just for stamping.

Comment: Hi matang, can you please share, what procedures did you do to apply for the work visa? I am in the same situation. Can you share any link that contains the application process? Actually, I couldn't find any form for that, did you apply for residency permit? Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: @maxpayne I just visited the German embassy and explained my situation. They gave me a checklist of documents required and said they can return my passport after validating and I need to submit it once my visa is approved only for a couple of days for stamping
You can check [HK German embassy](https://hongkong.diplo.de/hk-en/service/05-VisaEinreise/-/1611680)  for more information. You need to book appointment for a visit that is also available online [here](http://service2.diplo.de/rktermin/extern/choose_realmList.do?locationCode=hong&request_locale=en)

Comment: @matang, i am in same situation. can you elaborate `I need to submit it once my visa is approved only for a couple of days for stamping`. Does it mean during application date, you just showed passport and some other documents requested after that you were returned the passport. During the final phase, you had to give u your passport for couple of days?